# select2 container smaller than dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-select2

I've implemented angular-ui select2 into my application and it's working fine but the rendering of the select box container (above search) is smaller than the dropdown panel.

Here's what I mean:

[image]
[image]

HMTL:

```
<select 
    ui-select2="{placeholder:'Select a User', dropdownAutoWidth: true}"
    class="animated slideInDown" 
    id="entityDropDown" 
    ng-model="selectedUser" 
    ng-options="user as user.name for user in users" 
    ng-change="getUserInfo(selectedUser)"> <option>Place Holder</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want the drop down not to scroll and the list be completely visible?

Comment: The area above the search isn't the same size as the dropdown.

Comment: Have you tried adding a width attribute to the select input? Or check to see if styles are overriding the input width? Everything I'm seeing on the select2 site shows a width on the element itself (probably being set through js)

Comment: I tried but everything is being applied to the dropdown box and not that section above it. I can't even select that element in my console which is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your ctor parameters `width`:

```
<select
  ui-select2="{placeholder:'Select a User', dropdownAutoWidth: true, width: '100%'} >
</select>
```

Should work.

Comment: I ended up editing the css to force the .select2-container width.  That seemed to do the trick. I'm not sure why it's happening though.

Comment: I had the same pb at first. A css edit wasn't necy, I just used the three ctor parameters given. You tried this ctor dict? I'm curious.

Comment: yea but width 100% was too much. It didn't work however.

Comment: oh, hmmm, I use twitter bootstrap, so I'm in a floating span already. I sized the span, then width = 100.